# SQL select every xth row based on total number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with gps data:

```
lat, lon, timestamp
```

My queries select by a timestamp window:

```
SELECT * FROM gps WHERE timesamp >= '2016-12-12T02:00:00Z' AND timestamp <= '2016-12-12T03:00:00Z'
```

The resultset becomes way to big for larger timespans and I want to limit the size of the resultset. However, I still want the data to cover the entire timespan, but with reduced resolution. So instead of

```
LIMIT 1000
```

I want to select every n'th element based on my specified max resultset size and the actual size (count) of the data.

I want something like this

```
limit = 1000
totalCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gps WHERE timestamp >= ...
resolution = totalCount / limit
SELECT every resolution'th FROM SELECT * FROM gps WHERE timestamp >= ...
```

Comment: you can use window functions for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Work with `ROW_NUMBER()`, which is a "window function":

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.timestamp) as rnk,
           COUNT(*) OVER() as total_cnt
    FROM gps t
    WHERE t.timestamp between '2016-12-12T02:00:00Z' AND '2016-12-12T03:00:00Z') s
WHERE MOD(s.rnk,(total_cnt/1000)) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. t is not defined. So it should be SELECT gps.* instead. I will mark it as answered if you fix it

Comment: btw... Can I just add the limit / select count statement instead of <RESOLUTION> ?

Comment: @Chris Fixed, forgot to alias it. I also added the definition of `RESOLUTION` , just replace `1000` with your desired limit .

Comment: is there a way to do this without the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Then based on what will the row number rank the rows? @MattiasMartens

Comment: @sagi based on the natural ordering of the rows in the table, e.g. to get a sense of how the data is clustered in memory (it turns out you can do this by simply leaving the expression blank with `OVER()`)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to randomize the data and then use `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM gp
WHERE timesamp >= '2016-12-12T02:00:00Z' AND timestamp <= '2016-12-12T03:00:00Z'
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT x;
```

This doesn't guarantee an exact distribution across all timestamps.  But, it does make it possible to get exactly 1000 values.

Comment: order by random() may become unwieldy for large tables...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your limit is 1000 and you already know the `totalRowCount` this may also work, calculate "divisor" first like `totalRowCount/1000` then use it

```
select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over() from gps where ...) as mysubquery
where row_number % your_divisor = 0
```

If you want it sorted you can add that within the `over()` parens.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4ac9b6/20