# how to use where clause on row_number(postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select (select  sum(points) 
        from    points a 
        where   a.userid=userinfo.id 
            and userinfo.type='customer') as customerpoints
        ,* 
from users userinfo
left outer join points pd on pd.userid=userinfo.id 
where  type='customer'
and ( SELECT SUM(points)
      FROM  points a
      WHERE a.userid = userinfo.id
        AND userinfo.type = 'customer')>0                                                                                    
order by customerpoints asc
        ,id asc limit 50
```

i want to use row_number in the above query and use that row number in where clause

Comment: format your sql, submit raw data sample, show us example of what you expect to get

Comment: FIrst off, I'd avoid using sub-queries, use joins instead.

Comment: @ygorbunkov   check this query now

Comment: Show sample data and expected result so that we don't have to reverse engineer the requirement from your query to know what you actually want.  But,there are better ways to write  query to this for sure.

Comment: `row_number()` is not allowed in a `WHERE` clause.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I can't get what you want to achieve.. Why you do `subquery` with same condition and you already have join instead..

Comment: Use can use a subquery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69680897/32453

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the sample of your source data its hard to track the bug that's troubling you.
Following example demonstrates sorting by two columns:

```
select x.*
from (values ('Leo', 6), ('Mickey', 5), ('Don', 7), ('Raf', 6)) x(name, score)
order by 2,1
```

It returns

```
name    score
Mickey  5
Leo 6
Raf 6
Don 7
```

And you might notice that due to sorting fields order 'Don' is on the bottom of the list with the lowest score, though alphabetically he has to be on the top, and 'Leo' and 'Raf' having equal score are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: how to use row_number in the above query and use that row_number in where clause?

Comment: doing `select x.*, row_number() over (order by 1) as "row"...` could give you row number column, next you may wrap up that select into sub-query where you may do 'where' by that field, nevertheless, my main point here is that you don't really need row_number most of the times

Comment: can you please help me with my query??

Comment: that's what I started with - show sample of your source data (in tabular form), show desired sorting order (as another table), and let's see what can be done